# How can we get seek time from youtube player api?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm wondering how can we get pause,play and upto how much user seen the video data from the youtube player api ?Is this possible to get those details ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting current time : `getCurrentTimeMillis()`

For moving the video to the time indicated: `seekToMillis(int milliSeconds)`

To plays the selected video : `play()`

To pause the video: `pause()`

And to get info maybe the best option would be use JSON