# Get the start position before a seek on Youtube android player

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want to get the start and end position in Millisecond after à seek.

Actually, I get:

```
mYouTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSeekTo(int endPositionMillis) {

                Log.i("SEEK CURRENT MILLIS", String.valueOf(mYouTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis()));
                Log.i("SEEK ENDPOS MILLIS", String.valueOf(endPositionMillis));
            }
}
```

The problem is when the user move the cursor from the timeline, an event onSeekTo is launch, and when I'm inside my onSeekTo methode, I only got the endPositionMillis, but there is no way to get the timer/position before the seek.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the endTime of the video, use the  [`getDurationMillis()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#getDurationMillis()). For getting the current time use `getCurrentTimeMillis()` which you are already using then to go to a specific time of the video use either [`seekRelativeMillis()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#seekRelativeMillis(int)) or [`seekToMillis()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#seekToMillis(int)). With regard to your video not pausing before seeking to a specified time, it will still depend on your implementation if you want to pause the video before going to seeking to that time then playing it.

You can also check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32133926/5995040) (using web).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is when I try to move the cursor from the timeline as a user, it directly call onSeekTo() with the endPositionMillis as parameter. There is no way to get the initial position before the seek, like in other player where onSeek method take 2 params : initialPos and endPos